# Show reference at begin of document with conditions

Tags: cross-referencing, write

I'd like to show some reference at begin of document with some conditions. Here is the example code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{ctest}
\setcounter{ctest}{0}
\newenvironment{test}{%
  \refstepcounter{ctest}%
  \label{test:\thectest}%
  \par\noindent\thectest.\hspace{1em}%
}{}

\begin{document}
Ref here with some conditions such as \verb|\thectest > 1|

\ref{test:2}
\ref{test:3}

\begin{test}
  first
\end{test}
\begin{test}
  second
\end{test}
\begin{test}
  third
\end{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to write/append

```
\ifnum\thectest>1%
  \ref{test:\thectest}%
\fi%
```

to another file and input it in right place.

Comment: I don't understand the "write/append ... to another file and input it in right place" part. Why is "another file" there?

Comment: Something works like the contents. References are showed before, but conditions that judge whether to show the references are judged later so I think auxiliary file is needed.

Comment: You want to conditionally typeset something at the beginning of doc, based on the final value of some counter at the end of the same doc?

Comment: Yes this is what I want

Comment: What does "categories" represent? It is definitely a _bad practice_ to edit the question to a more general form. It makes discussions added between two question editions useless and more or less off-topic. You can always ask a new and follow-up question. It's free and not that hard.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

Package `totcount` is exactly for requirements like this.

`totcount` introduces a new consept "total counter". In the following example, `\newtotcounter{ctest}` creates a total counter and `\totvalue{ctest}` retrieves its total value (final value at the end of  last compilation).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{totcount}

\newtotcounter{ctest}

\newenvironment{test}{%
  \refstepcounter{ctest}%
  \label{test:\thectest}%
  \par\noindent\thectest.\hspace{1em}%
}{}

\begin{document}
\ifnum\totvalue{ctest}>2\relax
  <true code>
\else
  <false code>
\fi

\begin{test} content \end{test}
\begin{test} content \end{test}
% \begin{test} content \end{test}
\end{document}
```

---

In case you are curious about a direct implementation, see the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{totcount}

\newcounter{ctest}
\newcounter{ctest@total}
\setcounter{ctest@total}{-1}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \write\@auxout{\string\setcounter{ctest@total}{\arabic{ctest}}}%
}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{test}{%
  \refstepcounter{ctest}%
  \label{test:\thectest}%
  \par\noindent\thectest.\hspace{1em}%
}{}

\begin{document}
\ifnum\arabic{ctest@total}=-1\relax
  <a second run is required>
\else
  \ifnum\arabic{ctest@total}>2\relax
    <true code>
  \else
    <false code>
  \fi
\fi

\begin{test} content \end{test}
\begin{test} content \end{test}
% \begin{test} content \end{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What if the condition is not about the value of the counter but something else such as date and so on, is there a common way?

Comment: What does "so on" refer to? Do they, including the date, closely related to the current question?

Comment: Supporse the condition is more general. In detailed implemention of `test` environment, many extra information are assigned such as date and categories. And I will show the referrences by groups according to these information.

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck That's a second question. And please always provide detailed description and avoid fuzzy words as much as possible.

Comment: I did not realize there is a special solution for certain condition before I ask, but I think they can be thought as a single question, the latter is more general.

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck Now you realized. There is no simple and general comparison utility in (La)TeX. Integers, dimensions, booleans, strings, ... each has its own primitive conditionals. And conditionals for compound "data types" like dates calls for new macros per type.

Answer (score 0):

A rough version using `expl3` and write file to `\jobname .wq`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \g_test_int
\int_gset:Nn \g_test_int {0}
\tl_new:N \g_test_tl
\iow_new:N \l_myout_iow
\AtEndDocument{
  \iow_open:Nn \l_myout_iow {\c_sys_jobname_str .wq}
  \iow_now:Nx \l_myout_iow {\token_to_str:N \def \token_to_str:N \toshow{\g_test_tl}}
  \iow_close:N \l_myout_iow
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment {test} {}
{
  \int_gincr:N \g_test_int
  \customlabel{test\c_colon_str\int_use:N \g_test_int}{\int_use:N \g_test_int}
  \int_compare:nT
    {\g_test_int > 1}
    {
      \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_test_tl {\token_to_str:N \ref{test:\int_use:N \g_test_int}}
    }
  \par\noindent\int_use:N \g_test_int.\hspace{1em}%
} {}

\NewDocumentCommand {\myinput} {} {
  \file_if_exist:nT { \c_sys_jobname_str .wq }
    { \file_input:n { \c_sys_jobname_str .wq } }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\customlabel}[2]{%
  \protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {#1}{{#2}{\thepage}{#2}{#1}{}} }%
  \hypertarget{#1}{}
}
\def\toshow{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Ref here with some conditions such as \verb|\thectest > 1|

\myinput
\toshow

\begin{test}
  first
\end{test}
\begin{test}
  second
\end{test}
\newpage
\begin{test}
  third
\end{test}
\end{document}
```